# Convert float to varchar with IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query to convert `float` to `varchar` and its not working right.

```
select (CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), age,128)) iif(Age = '0','under 1 year', age)
from student
```

I cannot get it right.

the data

```
age
0
0
1
3
7
```

and become

```
age
under 1 year
under 1 year
1
3
7
```

not working with this query

```
select case when age = 0 then  convert(varchar(50), age, 'under 1 year' from student
```

Comment: And best not to store age as a float, best not to store it at all, store the Date of Birth, but if you have to store it use an int.

Comment: yay. it's working great. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select case when age = 0 then 'under 1 year' else convert(varchar(50), age) end
from student;
```

I do not recommend format 128.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) specifies:

> **126, 128, 129**    Included for legacy reasons; a future release could deprecate these values.

In addition, there is no reason to learn `iif()`.  `case` expressions are *standard* SQL and more versatile.

Comment: @user13636604: They're missing a trailing `)` after `end`